# How can I "fetch two" with python-mysql?

Tags: python, select, mysql-python

I have a table, and I want to execute a query that will return the values of two rows:

```
    cursor.execute("""SELECT `egg_id`
                      FROM `groups`
                      WHERE `id` = %s;""", (req_id))
    req_egg = str(cursor.fetchone())
    print req_egg
```

The column `egg_id` has two rows it can return for that query, however the above code will only print the first result -- I want it to also show the second, how would I get both values?

Edit: Would there be any way to store each one in a separate variable, with fetchmany?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in this case you can use fetchmany to fetch a specified number of rows:

```
req_egg = cursor.fetchmany(2)
```

edit:

but be aware: if you have a table with many rows but only need two, then you should also use a `LIMIT` in your sql query, otherwise all rows are returned from the database, but only two are used by your program.

Answer (score 1):

Call .fetchone() a second time, and it would return the next result.

Otherwise if you are 100% positively sure that your query would always return exactly two results, even if you've had a bug or inconsistent data in the database, then just do a .fetchall() and capture both results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Cursor.fetchmany(size=2)
```

Documentation for sqlite3 (which also implements dbapi): http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchmany